# Django restrict access to user objects

Tags: django, user-permissions

I have Node and User models which both belong to an Organisation. I want to ensure that a User will only ever see Node instances belonging to their Organisation.

For this I want to override the Node objects Manager with one that returns a query_set of User owned filtered results.

Based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset
the relevant *models.py* code I have is below:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='organisation')
    ...

class UserNodeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(organisation=self.request.user.organisation.first())


class Node(models.Model):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(
        Organisation, related_name='nodes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="UUID")
    ...

    objects = UserNodeManager
```

*views.py*

```
class NodeListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Node
```

**EDIT**
I can add custom query_set to individual views and this does work as below:

*views.py*

```
class NodeListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Node

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Node.objects.filter(organisation__users__id=self.request.user.pk)
```

However, my intention is to be DRY and override a 'master' query_set method at a single point so that any view (e.g. form dropdown list, API endpoint) will perform the user restricted query without additional code.

For example, I am using django's generic list views have a form for adding a Scan object which requires a user to select a Node the Scan belongs to. The form currently shows Nodes from other Organisations, which is against the permissions logic I need.

Unfortunately, the overridden Node.objects property does not seem to have any effect and any User can see all Nodes. Am I taking the right approach?

Comment: Do you try this `return super().get_queryset().filter(organisation__users_id=self.request.user.pk)`

Comment: This results in the error:
Related Field got invalid lookup: users_id

Comment: Try to change to have 2 underscores as `organisation__users__id`

Comment: @SergeyPugach: yes, it works for a query_set defined in a view but still does not have an effect as part of UserNodeManager class above.

Comment: How are you calling the `get_queryset` method? are you overriding all the manager methods(ie update, get , delete)?

Comment: @ruddra thanks, I have added my view code into the question. I am not explicitly calling `get_queryset`. I am not overriding any of the manager methods, only `get_queryset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
objects = UserNodeManager
```

You need to initiate `UserNodeManager` instance like this:

```
objects = UserNodeManager()
```

Also, it should throw error when you calling `YourModel.objects.all()` method(which is called from `get_queryset` method in view), because when it calls `get_queryset()` method, it does not pass `request`. So I think it would be a better approach:

```
class UserNodeManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self, request=None):
       qs = super(UserNodeManager, self).all()
       if request:
          return qs.filter(...)
       return qs
```

Or you can create a new manager method like this(optional):

```
class UserNodeManager(models.Manager):
    def user_specific_nodes(self, request):
       return self.get_queryset().filter(...)
```

Also update in the view:

```
class NodeListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Node

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Node.objects.all(self.request)  # where you can obviously use filter(...) or Model.objects.user_specific_nodes(self.request)
```

#### Update

*from comments*

Thing is that, you need to pass `request` with `filter()` or `all()`. In Generic views, the `get_queryset` method does not pass that information to `all()`. So you need to pass that either way. There is another way, to use a middleware like this [django-crequest](https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-crequest). You can use it like this:

```
from crequest.middleware import CrequestMiddleware

class UserNodeManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
       qs = super(UserNodeManager, self).all()
       request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()
       return qs.filter(...)
```

Comment: Thank you ruddra, I can add custom query_set to each view but am looking for a single point I can change that will restrict the Nodes queries application-wide. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: in your answer, you give the option to add `UserNodeManager` and also state that `NodeListView`'s `get_queryset` is to be overridden. However I understand this as all views will require the same `get_queryset` to be repeated, which is not DRY.  
My intention is to change the signle `UserNodeManager` so that any query (from any HTML view, API endpoint etc.) uses this 'master' queryset. Is this possible?

Comment: @user1330734 please see the update section of the answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of achieving this is by using groups and custom permissions. You might add a group for every organization and set the correct permissions for those groups over your Nodes.

Take a look to this article, it might help: [User Groups with Custom Permissions in Django](https://medium.com/@theparadoxer02/user-groups-with-custom-permissions-in-django-9eaea67b220e)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Raydel but if I am on the right track and can define the query_set on the model level, it seems it should be less work / maintenance than defining additional groups. The aim is to prevent insecure direct object referencing.

Comment: @user1330 I understand

Answer (score 0):

@ruddra thanks again for your guidance.

While your middleware example did not have effect for me (as user could still see others' objects), I was able to use that with the django documentation to finally implement the Manager similar to:

```
class UserDeviceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()
        return super().get_queryset().filter(organisation=request.user.organisation)
```